# Unnecessary ellipsis in question preview

Tags: bug, search

In the question preview, there is sometimes an ellipsis separating two phrases, although there are no words in between them in the actual question.

An example (from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+normalization):

[image]

The phrases in the two questions are:

- > [...] the count of parameters for batch normalization layer is weird, it is the channel * 4, but according to [...] [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476024/batch-normalization-parameters)
- > I have a problem with the dimensions of the scale and beta variables.
  >   [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412560/dimensions-in-batch-normalization)

Their representation in the question preview:

- > the count of parameters for batch normalization layer is ... weird, it is the channel * 4, but according to
- > I have a problem with the dimensions of the scale ... and beta variables.

This is a small UI/UX bug and possibly even opinion based. Personally, I find it a bit irritating.

Comment: *possibly even opinion based* - I don't think there's a grammatically correct justification for them being there. As you say, there aren't any words being snipped and I doubt the site is intentionally trying to add a tone of hesitation to posts. Also, I don't think they even meant to put ellipsis in the middle of the text like that. I think those are only supposed to show up at the end if the question has more content. You are objectively correct that it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Image unclear, needs more [free-hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138032/337830).

Comment: It looks to me like the site search is getting snippets of posts and putting them together with ellipses without regard to whether one snippet immediately follows another. And it could well be that "fixing" the issue isn't worth whatever speed would be lost.

Comment: @DavidFaber maybe not much speed lost: snippets are likely indexed to guaranty their display order, so it would just be a matter of testing that snippet1Index + 1 == snippet2Index. It's worth to report to ElasticSearch.

Comment: @JornVernee Clear now?

Answer (score 4):

My theory is that the question snippets shown in search where you have searched specific terms has a max of ~500 characters.

Results wise:

- If the question is < 500 characters, it seems to take the first ~200 characters, adds the ellipsis and then appends the remaining post if the search term appears again, which in this case is a direct continuation of the post, so the ellipsis makes no sense
- If the question > 500 characters, you'll see the ellipsis work in a *slightly* more effective manner, where it will take the first ~200 characters, plus another section of the post that contains the search term.
- If the search term only appears once at the start of the post, you don't see a continuation after the first ellipsis.

I guess it's trying to show relevant content based on the search, but they should just leave the content alone when it's < 500 characters, of whatever the limit is.